# Can’t connect to a Datamax-O'Neil E-4205A E-Class thermal printer when it is hooked up via Ethernet via a Netgear GS108E managed switch

Tags: networking, router, printing, printer

I've just recently bought a Datamax-O'Neil E-4205A E-Class thermal printer off of eBay, and I'm having some issues trying to connect to my network. Using direct Ethernet, it connects fine and is discoverable if I put the printer's IP into a browser. But I need to use a network switch to make the distance over to where it is going to be living.

Using a Netgear GS108E managed switch, I can't get it to connect at all to the network. According to the switch, it's sending and receiving packets, but I'm getting nothing when I put the IP into a browser or when I print a test page off of the printer.

I was trying to change the duplex speed of the printer and switch to see if it was a speed issue, but I found no luck. Lastly, I tried changing the IP settings from DHCP to static, and when I did that I must've messed something up because it's not discoverable at all now, even with a direct connection.

The printer works flawlessly using USB, but I'd prefer to use Ethernet.

I guess I have 2 problems:

- Figure out a way to switch back to DHCP.
- Figure out why network switch is preventing connection to the network.

Not sure if this matters, but my operating system is EndeavourOS with Arch kernel 6.1.2, and I have an Arris G36 modem/router.

Datamax-O'Neil doesn't exist as a company anymore and it seems to have been absorbed by Honeywell so finding online resources is pretty scarce with this printer.

Comment: It sounds like you have a DNS/routing issue rather than a printer issue. Does the switch work for other traffic?

Comment: @music2myear I managed to figure it out! Now I don't really know much about networks, but to my understanding it seemed like the IP of the printer was non-discoverable on my network because it was out of scope. The printer was out of scope for the other devices in my network, so I switched the IP address of my laptop to match the scope of the printer, and I was able to find it and change the IP address. The switch works flawlessly now and I have everything working. Thank you for your help.